# Mdx not removing hierarchy members based on existing filters

Tags: mdx, mondrian

On Date Dimension , I have 4 days (21,22,27,28) as day ..
I have time dimension which has hour. I selected only 7 from hour in time dimension. The available measure is Max Price. For [Time dimension.Hour].[7] only 2 days i.e 21 and 28 have values and null for 22 and 27. Now I want bottom 2 results based on filtering date (by max price). Following is the mdx query :

```
WITH 
  SET [XL_Col_Dim_0] AS 
    VisualTotals
    (
      (DISTINCT 
        Hierarchize
        (
          {
            Ascendants([Time dimensions.Hour].[7])
           ,Descendants([Time dimensions.Hour].[7])
          }
        ))
    ) 
  SET [XL_Row_Dim_0] AS 
    VisualTotals
    (
      (DISTINCT 
        Hierarchize
        (
          {
            {
              DrillDownLevelBottom
              (
                {[Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days]}
               ,2,
               ,[Measures].[Max Price]
              )
            }
          }
        ))
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize
    (
      Intersect
      (
        AddCalculatedMembers
        (
          {
            DrillDownLevel({[Time dimensions.Hour].[All Time dimensions.Hours]})
          }
        )
       ,[XL_Col_Dim_0]
      )
    )
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
   ,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize
    (
      Intersect
      (
        AddCalculatedMembers
        (
          {
            DrillDownLevel({[Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days]})
          }
        )
       ,[XL_Row_Dim_0]
      )
    )
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
   ,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM [mycube]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Max Price]
CELL PROPERTIES 
  VALUE
 ,FORMAT_STRING
 ,LANGUAGE
 ,BACK_COLOR
 ,FORE_COLOR
 ,FONT_FLAGS;
```

The problem here is it will return 27 and 28 although [Hour].[7] has no value for the date 27. Instead the dates that should be returned are 21 and 28.

EDIT
When I replace [Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days] with [Date dimensions.Day].[21],[Date dimensions.Day].[28] which are the available dates when [Hour].[7] is already used as slicer , things seems to work fine, but then if I do bottom 1 instead of 2, it still returns 2 results for day dimension which is wrong, it should return only 1. Seems like somehow DrillDownLevelBottom is not working as expected .

Comment: How come you do not use the `BottomCount` function if you'd like the bottom two from a list based on a measure?

Comment: @whytheq DrillDownLevelBottom is used to get the bottom most members of the set . Actually the query is generated by excel. I am trying to connect excel with mondrian.

Comment: Without a doubt this is the most complicated MDX code I have ever come across(My personal opinion, since I have rarely used these functions nor have seen anyone using much of them). Question: If this code is generated by excel, I guess you are not looking for a different query then. How can we help you?

Comment: @SouravA I am intercepting the excel query, Now thinking I will change the query I get from excel before sending to mondrian

Comment: I tried to replace {[Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days]} with Filter(
Filter({[Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days]},Not IsEmpty([Time dimensions.Hour].[7]))
,Not IsEmpty([Measures].[Min Price])) , but the result was not different ..

Comment: and replacing it with [Date dimensions.Day].MEMBERS would give me back all the days ..

Comment: Just a wild guess since I am not near my system, but from the looks of it, it seems there is a lot of scope for simplification. Will work on it when I am back.

Comment: @SouravA that would be awesome.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the query to look at `not isempty` members then you should use the function `NonEmpty`

```
NonEmpty({[Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days]})
```

If you only want to consider the days that are `NonEmpty` for the hour 7 then you use a tuple in the second argument of the `NonEmpty` function:

```
NonEmpty(
  {[Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days]}
  ,(
    [Time dimensions.Hour].[7]
   )
)
```

---

**Edit**

Please try this very simple script initially to ensure your `Not IsEmpty` logic is working ok:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Max Price] ON COLUMNS, 
    Filter(
      [Date dimensions.Day].Members
     ,Not IsEmpty([Time dimensions.Hour].[7])
    ) 
  ON ROWS 
FROM [mycube];
```

Maybe for each day there will exist every hour -try to add in a measure to the tuple used in the `IsEmpty` function:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Max Price] ON COLUMNS, 
    Filter(
      [Date dimensions.Day].Members
     ,Not IsEmpty(
            (
              [Time dimensions.Hour].[7]
             ,[Measures].[someMeasureInMyCube]
            )
          )
    ) 
  ON ROWS 
FROM [mycube];
```

Comment: Mondrian does not seem to support NonEmpty signature. I am using mondrian 3.7 at the moment, but did not see anything to suggest 4.2 supports NonEmpty as well .

Comment: Instead I tried using Filter({[Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days]},Not IsEmpty([Time dimensions.Hour].[7]))
, but that won't give me different as well ..

Comment: wow - that surprises me - `NonEmpty` is pivotal in Microsoft's implementation of `mdx`

Comment: even the query SELECT [Measures].[Max Price] ON COLUMNS,
BottomCount(
Filter([Date dimensions.Day].Members,Not IsEmpty([Time dimensions.Hour].[7])) 
,2,[Measures].[Max Price]
)ON ROWS
FROM [mycube] 
WHERE ([Time dimensions.Hour].[7]) ..
is returning only 21 instead or returning 21 and 28

Comment: @SucceedStha try an even simpler query to see what is happening: I'll amend my post.

Comment: using TAIL after filtering instead of BottomCount seems to give me the number of results I wanted .  Also I was wondering if [Date dimensions.Day].Members and [Date dimensions.Day].[All Date dimensions.Days] are the same ..